# Error 403 when connecting to the official Clash Royale API

Tags: java, httprequest, http-status-code-403

I keep getting Error 403 Invalid authorization, the token is totally correct.
Does anyone else use the Clash API? Couldn't find any working code with it so far.

This is the code I'm using for my test requests:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class Test {

    private static String token = "can't show that :)";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.clashroyale.com/v1/locations");

            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            InputStream content = (InputStream) con.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
            JsonElement je = jp.parse(in.readLine());
            String jsonString = gson.toJson(je);
            System.out.println(jsonString);

            con.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the error message, exactly?

Comment: This line `con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);` adds to the `token` string. You are certain the token is correct, but is `"Bearer " + token` correct?

Comment: That's the only reason I could think of why it is not working, but it says that in the official documentation so I would assume that

Comment: here is the error message: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://api.clashroyale.com/v1/locations

Comment: I think the base64 encoding of ``"Bearer" + token`` is missing?

Comment: tried it with base64, also error 403

Answer (score 0):

You can test this curl with your actual token to check that is actually valid.

```
curl -X GET \
  https://api.royaleapi.com/v1/locations \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer {{token}}' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'
```

Did you get your developer token following instructions on https://docs.royaleapi.com/#/authentication ?